# WebSocket в Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, websocket

На сервере(tcp) стоит python скрипт, на модуле socket, не могу подключиться, открываю Console в гугл хром и получается такй вывод:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://192.168.1.189:771/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: net::ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE
(anonymous) @ control.js:6
```

Сервер точно рабочий, через клиент на c++ все работает.
Вот код с помощью которго пытаюсь подключиться к серверу через js:

```
var connection = new WebSocket('ws://192.168.1.189:771');
connection.onopen = function () {
  connection.send('Ping'); // Send the message 'Ping' to the server
};
```

Comment: у вас на сервере точно вебсокет запущен, а не простой сокет?

Comment: Обычный сокет..

Comment: Ну вот и ответ на ваш вопрос. Это разные вещи.

Comment: А как возможно реализовать подключение к обычному сокету?

Comment: Может лучше сокет сервер заменить на вебсокет?

Comment: Не вариант, для контакта с этим сервером написанно много программ.

Comment: Тогда делайте прокси. Перебрасывайте сообщения с сокет соединения в вебсокет

Comment: А что, нету библиотек для TCP сокетов для js?